# Values from the openpyxl rows are not getting populated in the dictionary

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a excel sheet and I want to convert it to a dictionary by using openpyxl I didn't get proper solution.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(r"C:\Users\MADHU SANKAR\Downloads\Prjct data.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active
companies = {}
for row in sheet.iter_rows():
     #company_name = row[0]
     company_data = {
         'reg number': row[1],
         'Email ID': row[2],
         'Department': row[4],
         }
     companies[company_name] = company_data
print(companies)
```

The dictionary is being populated as **<Cell 'Sheet1'.B1>** instead of its inside cell value.

Comment: Any error with this code?

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Provide [mre] and explain what the problem is - e.g. expected vs actual output. Also edit the title for more descriptive title.

Comment: You have a wrong indentation line at the first line. Also, I believe you need to specify `filename = {excel path}` as documentation suggested. Check out how to read xlsx file with load_workbook: [link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html). Also, I believe this link may also help you [link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.reader.excel.html).

Comment: I have reframed the question correctly, if possible pleasse review it and re-post it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For your code the below value attribute for the row index could help, try this out.

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(r"C:\Users\MADHU SANKAR\Downloads\Prjct data.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active
companies = {}
for row in sheet.iter_rows():
    company_name = row[0].value
    company_data = {
         'reg number': row[1].value,
         'Email ID': row[2].value,
         'Department': row[4].value,
         }
    companies[company_name] = company_data
print(companies)
```